# ImageView extra padding issue

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

ImageView code :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:padding="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:src="@drawable/home_logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

API 17 and below : (The problem)

[image]

API 18 and above : (Desired result)

[image]

As you can see there is extra padding on left and right in the problem image, where in desired result its not there. Also I don't want to stretch the image and not even change the height.

PS: These blue boundaries are of "showLayoutBounds" option in developer settings.

Comment: Any reasons for negative votes ? If you check the question this is different problem than others..

Comment: Why don't you post the entire layout?

Comment: because its from my project, and problem is in this imageview only..
UPDATE : I mean only in ImageViews... and this is a sample

Comment: one question... you want the image to be eventually stretched, or you want it to fill the space eventually cutting some parts? Depending on outcome you want, you can use scaleType attribute with different values.

Comment: neither stretched nor cut out.. just maintain aspect ratio with height fixed

Comment: Seriously, post the entire layout. Other things could be affect the sizing of your ImageView.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, please check AnishMittal's answer.. it worked for me..

Comment: It's too bad we didn't know for sure there was a LinearLayout -- because we were missing the entire layout like I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:
Take a LinearLayout with android:layout_width = "wrap_content" and put above ImageView inside it.

Comment: It actually worked, can you explain what could be the possible reason ?

Comment: Taking ImageView separately let it occupy more space than required. Putting it in LinearLayout takes away that privilege.